# How can I apply different designs for Android and iOS - when developing with react.native?

Tags: react-native

I am developing an app with react native; How can I apply different designs to iOS and Android? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have not researched online properly before asking this question, there is clear docs about this topic in React-Native. Go check (this.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a stylesheet and use RN's `Platform` API to distinguish whether the OS is Android or iOS.

example code:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

const device = Platform.OS
const styles = {
  header: {
    backgroundColor: device === "android" ? "#424242" : "#F8F8F8"
  }
}

module.exports = styles
```